# ACF Map with custom styles field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, google-maps

I have an option page where i can create maps, i created a custom field to paste my own styles. What i need to do is pass this informations in my maps.js. What i have done is create an hidden div like this (i'm using timber) :

```
<div class="hidden" id="map-styles">{{ options.map_styles }}</div>
```

Then in maps.js i get this informations like this :

```
function initMap($el) {

// Find marker elements within map.
var $markers = $el.find(".marker");
var styles = document.getElementById("map-styles").textContent;

// Create generic map.
var mapArgs = {
zoom: $el.data("zoom") || 16,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
styles: styles,
};
```

But it's not working, however if i'm doing a console.log('styles'), i see my code and if i paste my code directly in my js file it's working.
Do you guys have any idea of how to solve this ? Is it a formating issue or something like that, I would really appreciate if you could put me on the right track.

You can see the map here : http://thefabulous.odns.fr/

Thanks

Comment: You should include a sample of what the map styles look like when you input them and what they look like when you output them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a look at your site and found the json map styles in your div `#map-styles`.

However your json is not quite valid. Not sure where you copied the style source from or wether acf is manipulating the output.

I cleaned up your style json so it is valid, [see validated version here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator/cb1f9760).

So with regards to integrating it into your `maps.js`, the option `style` doesn't exist, you need to modify `mapTypeControlOptions` to get your style registered as a `mapTypeId`

[See google `mapTypeControlOptions` docs here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/control#MapTypeControlOptions)

Here is what I added to your current script to get it working. Note this wont work unless you make sure your json is valid from your acf field.

```
// map args
var mapArgs = {
  zoom: $el.data("zoom") || 16,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [
      'custom_map_style',
      google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    ],
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL
  }
};

// set our map
var map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], mapArgs);

// get our json from #map-sytles div
var customStyle = JSON.parse($('#map-styles').text());

// create the custom styled map type object
var customStyleMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(customStyle, {
  name: 'Custom Style'
});

// set the custom styled map type against the map
map.mapTypes.set('custom_map_style', customStyleMap);
map.setMapTypeId('custom_map_style');
```

You will notice that i've added your custom style map as another option in `mapTypeIds`.

You can remove the default `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` or `google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE` or both... from `mapTypeIds`. Always nice to keep the satellite option in my opinion.

Here is a working demo on jsfiddle using your code from your site with the above tweeks.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/qcL7v9p6/

What would be cleaner is to output the json into a data attribute rather than a hidden div.

```
<div class="acf-map" data-zoom="19" data-style="{{ options.map_styles }}">
```

And get the json this way `$el.data('style');`

Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, 1000 thanks for your time.

Comment: No worries glad it worked for you.